# Matrices $AB$ and $BA$ identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

We have $n$ by $n$ matrices $A, B$ with complex entries. We denote $X=AB$ and $Y=BA$. We have to prove that $\det(I+X+X^2+X^3)=\det(I+Y+Y^2+Y^3)$.

I showed that we have the following equality: $AB(I+X+X^2+X^3)=A(I+Y+Y^2+Y^3)B$

So, if $\det(AB)\neq 0$ we get our result. What can I do for the case when $\det(AB)= 0$ ? Could it be something using the fact that $\det(X^4-I)=\det(X-I)\det(I+X+X^2+X^3)$ and that $\det(X-I)=\det(Y-I)$ ?

Comment: What is the ground field ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. complex numbers?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Sorry to ask this, but what do you mean by "ground field" ? I can't seem to understand thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use the following magic: 
$$\det(I+X+X^2+X^3)-\det(I+Y+Y^2+Y^3)$$
is just a polynomial of coefficients in $X$ and $Y$.
Invertible matrices form an open subset in all matrices, and since you proved that this polynomial equals $0$ on that subset, it also equals $0$ for all matrices.

P.S. I think there is a theorem saying the same, but I sadly can't recall the name of it.

Comment: but I sadly can't recall the name of it.]--> (Oscar) Zariski ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. could be the case. Though I looked up wiki and couldn't find that statement under his name.

Comment: Well it's [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology) because if you plug coefficients of $A,B$ into your difference, you get a polynomial in $2n^2$ variables. The set where your difference is $0$ is closed for  Zariski Topology and contains the one of invertible matrices (which is dense when the ground field is infinite), then you are done.

Answer (score 2):

It's sufficient to do it for the case $\det(AB)\ne0$. For $\det(AB)=0$
take sequences $A_n\to A$ and $B_n\to B$ with $\det(A_nB_n)\ne0$
and take limits.

Comment: I haven't used limits of matrices before. So i would write $\det(I+X_n+X^2_n+X^3_n)=\det(I+Y_n+Y^2_n+Y^3_n)$ and then take the limit?

Comment: @Asix yeah, just like that. This uses a bit of underlying stuff such as 'invertible matrices are dense in all square matrices' and 'all the functions here are continuous', hence such a sequence exists and you are allowed to take limits... but yeah, just take the limit.